# How to get the diff between contents of two directories in go lang

Tags: go, diff

I could get the diff between content of two directories by running the `diff` command through the `os` package as follows,

```
command := "diff --brief -r /home/kasun/Documents/Old-directory/ " +
    "/home/kasun/Documents/New-directory/"

out, err := exec.Command("sh", "-c", command).Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error occured")
    fmt.Printf("%s", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%s", out)
```

since `diff` is a command only available in `bash`, the binary formed by building the above code cannot be used to get diff in a `Windows` system. Is there any other way to achieve the same so that it will work on any platform, like performing the diff using standard go libraries. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> since diff is a command only available in bash, the binary formed by building the above code cannot be used to get diff in a Windows system

It can, if you install (unzip anywhere you want) the [latest Portable Git](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [`PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.14.1.windows.1/PortableGit-2.14.1-64-bit.7z.exe))

If you add that installation to your PATH, you do have diff (to be used in your Go program)

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 C:\
> where diff
D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\diff.exe
```

But if you don't want to rely on an existing thrid-party installed software (here Git), you might consider vendoring in your project [**`spcau/godiff`**](https://github.com/spcau/godiff).
If does have a [`diff` implementation for Windows](https://github.com/spcau/godiff/blob/master/godiff_windows.go).

---

Note that, with Git 2.17 (Q2 2018), Go is better recognized by Git, since "`git diff`" and friends learned `funcname` patterns for Go language source files.

See [commit 1dbf0c0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1dbf0c0ad6cabfc35aa1896b4d94f4ee811ba803) (01 Mar 2018) by [Alban Gruin (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 077cde9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/077cde91d226c305523645a0f30b6955d4aaf9c9), 08 Mar 2018)</sup>

> ### `userdiff`: add built-in pattern for Golang
>
> This adds `xfuncname` and `word_regex` patterns for Golang, a quite
>   popular programming language. It also includes test cases for the
>   `xfuncname` regex ([t4018](https://github.com/git/git/tree/1dbf0c0ad6cabfc35aa1896b4d94f4ee811ba803/t/t4018)) and updated documentation.
>
> The `xfuncname` regex finds functions, structs and interfaces.
>   Although the Go language prohibits the opening brace from being on its own
>   line, the regex does not makes it mandatory, to be able to match
>   `func` statements like this:
>
> ```
> func foo(bar int,
>     baz int) {
> }
> ```
>
> This is covered by the test case [`t4018/golang-long-func`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1dbf0c0ad6cabfc35aa1896b4d94f4ee811ba803/t/t4018/golang-long-func).
>
> The `word_regex` pattern finds identifiers, integers, floats, complex
>   numbers and operators, according to the go specification.

Answer (score 0):

The right way may be to recursively walk the directory and check & match md5 checksum for each of the corresponding files. However that's tedious, if you are sure your file structure is not too big or it's allowed, then just create a tar gz of both the directories and then compute & compare the md5 checksum or sha256sum on the tarballs.